# Unable to formulate a prover9 axiom

Tags: theorem-proving

I'm trying to teach basic set theory to Prover9. The following definition of membership seems to work very well (the second axiom is just to make lists unordered):

```
member(x,[x:y]).
[x,y]=[y,x].
```

With this, I can have Prover9 prove 'complicated' things like `member([A,B],[C,[A,B]])` and others.
However, I must be doing something wrong when I use it to define subsets:

```
subset(x,y) <-> (member(z,x) -> member(z,y)).
```

Prover9 clausifies this as `subset(x,y) | -member(z,y)` and uses it to prove false clauses, like `subset([A],[B,C])`.
What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Prover9, but if this is similar to a logic language, then `member(z,x) -> member(z,y)` is true if z is not a member of x. Your rule `subset(x,y) <-> (member(z,x) -> member(z,y))` might be interpreted as "subset(x,y) if and only if there exists a z such that member(z,x) -> member(z,y)", instead of what you intended: "subset(x,y) if and only if for all z, member(z,x) -> member(z,y)".

Comment: hmm... I understand that member(z,y) would be true if z is not a member of x (because False implies anything), but why do you say that the whole clause `member(z,x) -> member(z,y)` would be true?

Comment: I don't know if prover9 treats unbound variables on the right hand side as universal or existential.  If it treats them as existential, then that could explain your issue.

Comment: I just found this in the manual "Free variables in clauses and formulas are assumed to be universally quantified at the outermost level." So I think what I wrote initially is equivalent to `subset(x,y) <-> all z (member(z,x) -> member(z,y))`.

Comment: I found this example: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/examples/Aug-2007/misc/subset_trans.in  The input to the set of support (sos) does clausify differently there.  You might find links with some work done in set theory in OTTER useful also such as these: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~belinfan/research/autoreas/index.html http://www.settheory.com/Omodeo/setOtter/prefaceOnAxioms.html

Answer (score 1):

Your "second axiom ... just to make lists unordered" looks suspicious.

Note `[x,y]` is a two-element list. So your axiom is saying nothing about lists in general. Your 'complicated' examples, are still 2-element lists. So not very complicated. I think you'll be unable to prove `member(A, [C, B, A])`

Contrast that `[x:y]` in your first axiom is a 1-or-more-element list. The `y` might be nil, or might be any number of elements. IOW `y` is a list, whereas in `[x,y]`, `y` is an element of a list.

See http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/manual/2009-11A/, 'Clauses & Formulas' at 'list notation'.

I'd go:

```
member(x, [x:y]).
member(x, z) -> member(x, [y:z]).
```

(But that defines a bag, not a set.)

> I think the quantification over variables is a red herring.

**Edit:** Errk. I'm wrong. So I don't know why I got this result:

> The example that @Doug points to doesn't need to quant `z` 'inside'
>   the rhs of equivalence. You can just remove all the explicit
>   quantification, and the proof still works.

OK. Let's apply the rewrite rules per the Manual 'Clauses & Formulas' at "If non-clausal formulas are entered ...".

That definition of subset is an equivalence (aka bi-implication); rewrite as two separate axioms: 'forwards' and backwards' implications; rewrite each of those using `p -> q` ==> `-p | q`.

In the 'forwards' direction we get:

```
-subset(x, y) | (member(z, x) -> member(z, y)).
```

Doesn't matter whether the `z` is quantified narrow or wide.

In the 'backwards' direction:

```
-(member(z, x) -> member(z, y)) | subset(x, y).
```

Here if we quantify `z` narrowly around the implication, that's inside the scope of negation; and so different to quantifying across the whole formula.

**Conclusion:** both your definition of `member( )` and of `subset( )` are wrong.

BTW Are you sure you need to define `member`? The proof @Doug points to just takes `member(x,y)` as primitive.